# Bad request, missing form - Stripe integration not showing on Netlify

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, netlify

I am trying to integrate Stripe Checkout into Netlify Website(website is live). It doesn't seem to be running the server side or client side of my code giving me a response of "Bad request, missing form". Seems like it's not picking up my post request. I also include the netlify.toml and _redirect folder for it to work. It worked in the localhost but it's not running now. How can I fix this?

I have provided my server.js and checkout.js below:

**checkout.js**

```
const button = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
     body: JSON.stringify({
      //  items: [{ id: "Black Sweatsuit"},
      //          { id: "Grey Sweatsuit"},
      //          { id: "Red Sweatsuit"},
      //          { id: "Blue Sweatsuit"},
      //          { id: "Black T-Shirt"},
      //          { id: "Blue T-Shirt"},
      //          { id: "Purple T-Shirt"}
      //  ],
     }),
  })
    .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) return res.json()
    return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
  })
    .then(({ url }) => {
    window.location = url
  })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e.error)
  })
})
```

**server.js**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_live_XXXXXXX')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())



const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://www.kimiee-kreates.com';

const storeItems = new Map([
   [1, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "El Chapo"}],
   [2, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Joker"}],
   [3, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Joker"}],
   [4, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "She Hit Different"}],
   [5, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Icy Girl"}],
   [6, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Girls don't Cry"}],
   [7, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Black Kaws"}],
   [8, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Orange Kaws"}],
   [9, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Scarface Monoly"}],
   [10, { priceId: 'price_XXXX',name: "Run, Rick & Morty"}],
   [11, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Glo Sun"}],
   [12, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Child's Play"}],
   [13, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Scream"}],
   [14, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Vegeta - Blue & Black"}],
   [15, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Goku"}],
   [16, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Juice"}],
   [17, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Rick & Morty"}],
   [18, { priceId: 'price_XXXX', name: "Vegeta"}],
])

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
          { 
            price:'price_1M334EJGTDSvYp0wR4rUafhO',
            quantity: 1,
            adjustable_quantity: {
              enabled: true,
            }
          },
          { 
            price:'price_1M334MJGTDSvYp0wRqy65q46',
            quantity: 1,
            adjustable_quantity: {
              enabled: true,
            }
          },
        ],
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
          mode: 'payment',
          success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
          cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
          automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
      });
    
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    });
```

Comment: Seems to be a Netlify set up issue. https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-forms-bad-request-missing-form/77761

Comment: Hey thanks @orakaro but that link didn't work

Comment: @orakaro I believe it's in my redirects and netlify.toml file is there a way to fix it the right way?